# Movement of the point $A$ on the cylinder

Tags: geometry, vectors

We have a point $A$ on the top of a cylinder with radii $1$.After $2.5$ rolls find the movement of point $A$.(Take $\pi=3$ if needed)

[image]

For finding the movement of point $A$ we should use pytagoras to find the movement but I had a disscustion with my teacher about the value of $A'B$ I strongly belive that $A'B=2.5*permiter=2.5*2*\pi=15m$ but our teacher tells that $A'B=2.5*2radii=10m$ I don't know why but I strongly belive my answer.So we decided to ask it here to get an answer .A video will be helpful a lot but I don't know how to make one.Please make for me one or tell me how to make one.Thanks.

Comment: Your answer is the correct one!

Comment: @RobertZ Do you know how can I make a video?

Comment: Don't say $\pi=3$ it is an abuse of numbers.  It is not true and it makes your work more difficult to follow.  I think you mean to say that $A'B =2.5\cdot \text{circumference}$, (and not perimeter.)  And your logic is correct.  The cylinder rolls across every point along its circumference as it completes each revolution.

Comment: @DougM Do you know how can I make a video.

Comment: How about you resort to physics.  Take a coin and roll it across a ruler.  Measure the radius with the ruler and the distance traveled per revolution.

Comment: @Taha Akbari I am sorry, I have never seen a video here? However your question is clear. Why do you want to make a video?

Comment: @RobertZ Because our teacher won't accept.

Comment: @DougM We made it but it is hard to find the value exactly and our teacher didn't accept.

Comment: I don't know how to make a video.  Videos are okay as a teaching tool, but they don't prove anything, as it is to easy to lie with animation.  If your teacher won't believe the observations in a physical demonstration, a video won't be any better.  How about this approach,  use a polygon.

Comment: The "movement of point $A$" is not clear to me. Do you mean simply the straight-line distance between its start and end points? This is not the same as the distance travelled, because it moves on a curve. (But if you mean the straight-line distance, then trivially it is $5\pi$, as you say.)

Comment: It's curious the teacher answer doesn't involve $\pi$. You must fire the teacher.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here it is an animation, making the answer trivial:

[image]

The distance travelled along the $x$-axis is $5\pi$ and the distance travelled along the $y$-axis is $2$.

Comment: +1 for the nice animation. But how does it make the answer any more trivial than it already was?

Comment: @TonyK: you may now "see" the segment joining the travelling point and the corresponding point on the initial circle. That should make easier to decompose the movement of the travelling point as the composition of a rotation and a translation, with related speeds.